# Access multidimensional array by string with delimiter

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

suppose i have a multidimensional array like something like this:

```
<?php

$array = array("test1" => array("test2" => array("test3" => 1)), ... foo1 = array("foo2" => 2));

?>
```

i want to access an array element by passing a string like `"test1.test2.test3"` to a function which in turn calls the array element. I could use `eval()` by replacing the string with `[]` (calling `$array["test2]["test3"]` ...) but i wonder if there is a different more solid approach in calling a array element without traversing through all of its depth or use `eval()`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
function get_multi($arr, $str) {
    foreach (explode('.', $str) as $key) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
            return NULL; 
        }
        $arr = $arr[$key];
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Symfony provides a [PropertyAccess](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html) component for this.

> The PropertyAccess component provides function to read and write from/to an object or array using a simple string notation.