# How to get value from nested array using string

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
$temp = array( '123' => array( '456' => array( '789' => '0' ) ),
               'abc' => array( 'def' => array( 'ghi' => 'jkl' ) )
             );
```

I have a string like this:

```
$address = '123_456_789';
```

Can I get value of `$temp['123']['456']['789']` using above array `$temp` and string `$address`?

Is there any way to achieve this and is it good practice to use it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. For arrays, yes this works and is normal usage. For strings no. And they are not related. Arrays are structured data, while strings are just a bunch of characters in a row.

Comment: Of course you could parse out the $address string, get the 3 keys from it and then use them to address the correct value in $temp, but why? Is there a use case for this? Knowing how this will be used could greatly affect the answer.

Comment: Search here, your question is answered already.

Comment: does eval() count as good practice though?

Comment: @GolezTrol: Actually I have a string something like this `123_456_789`. It means there is a value at `$temp['123']['456']['789']` that need to be fetched. I don't know how to execute this in PHP. Please review the question again.

Comment: @Typeless `eval` is just one way to answer the first part of the question. The second part is kind of opinion-based, in my opinion.

Comment: @Awan - in that case, just explode() your string by underscore and use the split results to address the array...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access multidimensional array by string with delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520048/access-multidimensional-array-by-string-with-delimiter)

Comment: If you listen to Rasmus Lerdorf very words *if you're using eval() to do it, you're doing it wrong*, that's might be because you're aproaching your data the wrong way. Loop through it, explode the string and use it as parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a simple function that accepts an array and a string address where the keys are separated by any defined delimiter. With this approach, we can use a for-loop to iterate to the desired depth of the array, as shown below.

```
<?php
function delimitArray($array, $address, $delimiter="_") {
    $address = explode($delimiter, $address);
    $num_args = count($address);

    $val = $array;
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $num_args; $i++ ) {
        // every iteration brings us closer to the truth
        $val = $val[$address[$i]];
        }
    return $val;
    }

$temp = array("123"=>array("456"=>array("789"=>"hello world")));
$address = "123_456_789";
echo delimitArray($temp,$address,"_");
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hello if string $address = '123_456_789'; is your case then you can use explode function to split the string by using some delimeter and you can output your value

```
<?php
$temp = array('123' => array('456' => array('789' => '0')),
    'abc' => array('def' => array('ghi' => 'jkl')),
);
$address = '123_456_789';
$addr = explode("_", $address);
echo $temp[$addr[0]][$addr[1]][$addr[2]];
```

Comment: \[Editing my previous coment\] It actually works and is very simple. Might be 'prettier' if fit inside a function, but anyway +1 :)

Comment: Number of elements in `$addr` may be different. So it will not work in case of `123_456`.

Comment: @Awan until the `explode`, everything is fine. If you build a function to verify your array level before applying `$addr` as parameter, you'll get it to any string you have (in the same pattern)

Comment: If the array varies in length then I would take a look at @Typeless' solution

Answer (score 0):

Using [this array library](https://github.com/minwork/array) you can easily get element value by either converting your string to array of keys using explode:

```php
Arr::get($temp, explode('_', $address))
```

or replacing `_` with `.` to take advantage of dot notation access

```php
Arr::get($temp, str_replace('_', '.', $address))
```

Another benefit of using [this method](https://minwork.gitbook.io/array/common-methods/get-getnestedelement) is that you can set default fallback value to return if element with given keys does not exists in array.