# PHP-> variable vars - arrays columns

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function which receives unlimited number of arguments.
(I am using func_get_args for that)

Example: `function generate($one, $two, $three, ...)`

Each one of the parameters represents a column in another array (let's call it `$array`).

I want to receive the value of the another array on `$array[$one][$two][$three]`

That means that the number of `"[]"` is unlimited

I have tried to generate a var in var for this.

```
<?php

  $ron = array("sir" => "yes");
  $name = 'ron["sir"]';
  echo var_dump(${$name});
?>
```

My result:

> Notice: Undefined variable: ron["sir"] in 
>   C:\Users\ronr\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\lol.php on line 5 NULL

Comment: for what i am looking https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple I am not sure it is possible to do it as you want to

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264853/how-to-get-value-from-nested-array-using-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the args as a path to array value, you can try this:

```php
$result = $array;
$args = func_get_args();

foreach($args as $arg) {
  $result = $result[$arg];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Ive thought about something similar but didn't think It is the right way. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the error is correct, you are defining a variable named `ron["sir"]`, something like this:

```
${'ron["sir"]'} = 'foobar';
echo ${'ron["sir"]'};
```

. To show the value of `sir` in the `$ron` array, it should be:

```php
$ron = array("sir" => "yes");
$name = 'ron';
var_dump(${$name}["sir"]);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for trying to help. Please read the rest of my question. Thanks again

Comment: _...read the rest of my question..._ What exactly do you mean? @RonRofe

Comment: If we have 4 arguments in the function - "hello", "its", "me", "here" ----- So I want to receive the value of the array on $array["hello"]["its"]["me"]["here"]

Comment: I suppose the real question is "can I use an interpolation to access to an array"

Comment: @RonRofe what if the index does not exists? what will happen then?