# PHP Selecting unknown depth of array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm going to try to make this as simple as possible.
A dot notation string gets sent to a function, so for example, this would be the string.

```
'user.id'
```

Then I explode the dot to give me an array of names

```
$dotNotation = explode(".", $variable);
```

And now I need to use these names to select from another variable like so

```
$row[$dotNotation[0]][$dotNotation[1]]
```

So this would be

```
$row['user']['id']
```

However, I need it to be dynamic, it can be any depth i.e there can be any number of dots. I'm totally stuck on how to achieve this.

Comment: If you just want to retrieve the item - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264853/how-to-get-value-from-nested-array-using-string

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate through all the keys and retrieve the value:

```
function getDotNotationValue($dotNotation, $row) {
   $dotNotationArray = explode(".", $dotNotation);
   foreach($dotNotationArray as $key) {
      $row = $row[$key];
   }
   return $row;
}

$row = ["test1" => ["test2" => ["test3" => "value"]]];
$string = "test1.test2.test3";
echo getDotNotationValue($string, $row);
```